# Sending a request to retrieve the data from Django

Tags: html, django, apache2, mod-python

I am doing a Web project, where I am using HTML5 and Django to store database in sqlite3. The part being, since I had to use python, I installed mod_python for apache2. Now the thing is I went through many sites for head start to store the data and retrieve it. When I check in google related to how to use mod_python I did get certain information on how I can send a request to a .py file and then execute it. But with Django documentation providing a tutorial which is to develop a polling webApp, I am not finding it measurable to the part I am trying to achieve.

I want to send the request from an Html file where I have a search box and some radio buttons, to Django through Apache2 (mod_python) and then access my database in sqlite3. Please could anyone give me brief idea on whether I am doing it right? Also if yes, can u give me a hint as in how can I send the request from HTML file to the database from Django and mod_python being used? I am a bit confused with Django tutorial.
Please if anyone can just let me know what exactly I should do! Or if any link with a proper guidance would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to guide you without see some code you have tried as I wouldn't know where to begin.  Even though the django tutorial is a polling app it is an excellent place to start.  That tutorial goes through the general structure of how a django app works which includes data to and from the database.  Once you've written the polling app you can begin modifying it slightly to get closer to what you want.  Also, yes, mod_wsgi as Ignacio said.

Comment: @wilbbe01 I have the site created with JQuery and CSS3, now the problem i faced over there is that Django din't help me detect the event. So i was guided by a professor to use Apache2 with mod_python. where i can load the page using Apache2 and then send a request to Django to store the data. Please correct me if I am missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, if you can install and use `mod_wsgi` instead of `mod_python`, you should -- `mod_python` hasn't been supported for years.  I'd also strongly recommend that you use anything other than SQLite for a production web application -- SQLite doesn't cope well with multiple simultaneous transactions.

If you're stuck using `mod_python`, then see the [Django documentation for using mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/).

Once you've got that working, the rest of your questions can be answered by the Django Tutorial, particularly part 4, which covers the use of HTML forms with Django views and templates:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: I tried using Django for calling the Html with urls.py file, where i could specify the first loading page, but then the Jquery wasnt supported by Django. I mean, the UI with Jquery dint work, so i was told by a professor to use Apache2 where ill load the page and then send the request to Django to store it into database.

Comment: Your jQuery file needs to be treated as a 'media' file by Django and served up directly by Apache.  The mod_python documentation addresses this.  No one's hiding any information from you, and this isn't rocket science.  Given that this is a homework assignment, you'll have to solve this on your own.

Comment: it aint any assignment. See the thing is, with mistakes is what we learn. I wasnt getting any result of it, so had many doubts. May be my approach was wrong in some areas. that doesnt mean everyone should be brilliant to understand each and every concept. For u it may not be a rocket science, but a newbie sometimes would feel it..

Comment: @Nagaraj, my apologies:  I saw the reference to 'professor' and made an assumption.  In the meantime, sometimes the best way to solve a problem is to break it into individual pieces, and solve each one sequentially, instead of trying to do everything in one shot.  Get Django installed and working with mod_python first.  Then get your static files working.  Then get your forms working.  Finally tackle the AJAX (jQuery) pieces.  You'll also find it easier to get help here if you ask questions that are focused on one piece, instead of mixing everything together.